# What is the path of ip_input.c?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, source-code

The ip_rcv funcion defined in the ip_input.c
file, is responsible for delivering the datagrams to a higher
layer protocol or forwarding it to another host. It consists
of functions and netfilter hooks that process an incoming
datagram.

I use Ubuntu but I can't find ip_input.c. I need direct path of ip_input.c
before install...
[image]

during install...
[image]
after install...
[image]
and resutl...
[image]

Comment: You do not have any kernel *sources* installed. Also, why even bother doing this locally when there's tons of sites that let you browse the Linux source code?

Comment: @DanielB: grep, find etc. work *much* better on a local copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` for it on your local copy of the kernel sources:

```
$ cd /usr/src/linux
$ find . -name ip_input.c 
./net/ipv4/ip_input.c
```

And there you have the path.

Comment: dear you can see above image .i use ubuntu 16 but i cant find ip_input.c.
what is your linux distribution and what is its version?

Comment: You have only installed the kernel *headers*, not the kernel source. `apt-cache search linux-source` shows you what versions of the kernel source you can install (using `apt-get install`, or whatever you prefer to install packages). It will install the sources under `/usr/src/linux-source-*version*`. It's recommended to make a symlink `/usr/src/linux` to the source that you used to compile the kernel or to the kernel version that is running on your machine (some utilities make use of this).

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to be root to inspect the kernel sources. Don't login as root unless you want to do sysadmin work. And even then `sudo` is better - less room for mistakes.

Comment: Tanks dear,I installed it but now I want to know if I change contents of ip_input.c ,this change effect on my Linux?

Comment: dirkt in ip_input.c there are functions that kernel need to use them.so when ip_input.c there was not in my linux how my  kernel have used that funcions? you know 10 min ago i download ip_input.c

Comment: Ubuntu and every other distribution uses a precompiled kernel image (`dpkg -i '*linux-image*' | grep ^ii` to see which ones you have installed). This image contains the compiled functions in ip_input.c, among lots of others. If you tell us *why* you are interested in these functions (if you don't just want to read the source code, which, from your questions, is maybe not what you want, though I initially assumed it was), we may be able to help you better. :-)

Comment: Dear dirkt , you are kind .I want to change Linux function. But i have basic knowledge about Linux.I have installed Linux and want to change some function.i mean ,i want to customize my Linux . what should i do? Should i download kernel and change then compile it? or should i change my current Ubuntu without compiling?Please help me if you can.

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the Linux function, you need to change the source, compile it, and install the kernel. However, with just basic knowledge, you won't be able to do that, because you won't how how to change the source. What do you want to change, and why do you want to change it? What is your goal? Modify datagrams? There's probably a different way to do it.(like the network filter features of the kernel).

Comment: Dear dirkt ,I have new view on network and can't accept this roles for network.i want to create new network protocol,i think if i focus on issue i can do that.i know TCP/IP but  i don't like work with simulator.i think i can.
Dirkt, you are polite and kind person.thanks for your help .